# onclick div open selectmenu in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, onclick

I have issue regarding **JQm selectmenu widget**, what I am doing is opening the select menus on a container in which it is contained.

**Fiddle Demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/4CKae/1/

**My HTML:-**

```
<div class="container" onClick="$('#select-choice-7').selectmenu('open');">
    <label for="select-choice-7" class="select">Select, native menu3</label>
    <select name="select-choice-7" id="select-choice-7" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am trying to open the `selectmenu` through inline jquery `onClick="$('#select-choice-7').selectmenu('open');"` but it shows some some weird errors in my firebug console.

**Console Says:-**

[image: Firebug Console]

```
too much recusion
```

My Firefox v19 shows this error on console and chrome unfortunately crashes...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the weird error please from the console.

Comment: `too much recursion` from jquery.js

Comment: Please, provide a example in jsFiddle.

Comment: I tried to make one, it crashed my browser! Too many errors. Something is not right with either the way you've written this code or jQM!

Comment: Inline JS may work in this case but i dont know why it is not working...

Comment: I don't think this part of your code is your problem, because it runs fine in JSFiddle for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4CKae/

Comment: Show us more of the html, i want too see how its al built up.

Comment: Question updated check fiddle... I am using Firefox v19...

Comment: I would suggest moving the code for the handler into the code and out of the markup.

Comment: Remove `'open'` from `$('#select-choice-7').selectmenu('open');`

Comment: @PiLHA show no errors but still native menu not appearing...

Comment: @SaurabhLP see this http://jsfiddle.net/emwke/

Comment: @PiLHA that also not a success... is it working for you?

Comment: @SaurabhLP Perfectly with FF 23.0.1 and Firebug 1.12.0. It does not show the error, perhaps you are confusing because the firebug in jsFiddle does not clear the console to re-run. Are you getting the error every time you click on the dropdown?

Comment: If I remove the handler from the markup (using chrome) and put this in the code, it works: ` $('#select-choice-7').selectmenu();` http://jsfiddle.net/8GQx4/

Comment: @PiLHA it shows no errors on console but it also doesn't shows the native menu list popup on clicking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include the `<select>` in the `onclick` element, it will make it a forever loop, working demo

**Updated:**
http://jsfiddle.net/4CKae/6/

```
<label for="select-choice-7" class="select" onclick="$('#select-choice-7').selectmenu('open');">Select, native menu3</label>
```

Or may be some checking could fix it

Comment: `label` could be made as `position:absolute;` to click through the container by css..

Answer (score 0):

I think **quotes** is the problem.

Try this

```
onClick='$("#select-choice-7").selectmenu("open");'
```

instead of

```
onClick="$('#select-choice-7').selectmenu('open');"
```

Comment: this shouldn't matter, double and single quotes mean the same thing in js and html

Comment: @SaurabhLP I'm getting the select menu, but it is not covering the whole div

Comment: @user1671639 it should cover the whole div if your implementing in a whole container inline html...

Answer (score 0):

markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <label for="select-choice-7" class="select">Select, native menu3</label>
    <select name="select-choice-7" id="select-choice-7" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$('#select-choice-7').selectmenu();
```

Note there is no click handler on the container here and no "open" parameter.

Fiddle (tested in Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/8GQx4/

Comment: Version 28.0.1500.95 m - seems to work for me.  What error do you see in your console?  I click the select and see the options.  Seems odd.

Comment: it seems like it opens on clicking the label of the select menu... i have tested it on opera mobile it works their but not in desktop browsers... NO errors also...